# Overide Defaultappassociations.xml and let user select the application

Tags: windows-10, sccm

I am working on Win 10 upgrade activity. As you know we can select application for file extension. So, those file will open on that app. e.g. html files only open in Chrome when user double click on that.
We can create XML file (DefaultAppAssociations.xml) and place it in C:\windows\system32

Now, I got the request to make one application default but let user decide if they want any other app. Is there any way to handle such things because defaultappassociations.xml will hard code this. Every time machine restart and it will set the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only possible as part of the operating system deployment or rather for newly created user profiles.

The command ([official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-default-application-association-servicing-command-line-options)):

```
Dism.exe /online /Import-DefaultAppAssociations:<path to exported xml>
```

However as I said you cannot alter existing profiles that way. Altering existing profiles in any way that is not the force via gpo is afaik not possible anymore because Microsoft does not want to allow it. A pretty stupid decision but at least you can tell whoever made the request that it is by MS design.